# Detect that cookies have been deleted without page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

After successful login I set:

```
$rootScope.globals = {
    currentUser: {
        username: username,
        token: token
    }
};

var cookieExp = new Date();
cookieExp.setHours(cookieExp.getHours() + 1);

$cookies.putObject('globals', $rootScope.globals, { expires: cookieExp });
```

When I "Clear all history" in Mozilla Firefox, user token remains and I can navigate in restricted contents until I make explicit page refresh. Is there any way to detect that credentials have been deleted without page refresh?

Comment: Is this a case you really need to handle? Wouldn't the user who clears their history also close the tab of your app? But what you could do is define an interval and check for a change in cookie value.

Comment: In my case, it is not necessary handle but still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be in sync with cookies, `globals` should make calls to $cookies on every use, e.g. be a single source of truth:

```
app.service('globals', function ($cookies) {
  this.get = function (key) {
    return $cookies.getObject('globals');
  };
  this.set = function (key, obj) {
    var cookieExp = new Date();
    cookieExp.setHours(cookieExp.getHours() + 1);
    $cookies.putObject('globals', obj, { expires: cookieExp });
  };
});
```

Since cookie requests may be inefficient, the service can optionally provide expiring cache.

Using root scope as global variable scope [is antipattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil).